# 既存クラスのメソッドに追加のオプションをつける方法

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

Rubyで`selenium-webdriver`を使用してるときに

```
Selenium::WebDriver.for :phantomjs
driver.find_element(:id, "foo").clear
driver.find_element(:id, "foo").send_keys("bar")
```

のようにテキストボックスを埋める前に`clear`で空にすることがよくあるために
`send_keys(arg1, clear: true)`で事前に内容を消してから実行できるメソッドで置き換えをしようとしましたがうまくいきませんでした。

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Element
  alias_method :send_keys_orig, :send_keys
  def send_keys(*args, clear_flag: false)
    clear if clear_flag
    send_keys_orig(*args)
  end
end
```

ですと、`SystemStackError: stack level too deep`になってしまいました。
またメソッド名と同名のハッシュキーが使えなかったため`clear_flag`にしています。

現状は別名のメソッドを使っています。既存クラスのメソッド置き換えは危険なのは理解してるのですが、個人的に使うものなので、長いメソッド名よりもキーワード引数で指定したく考えています。

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Element
  def send_keys_after_clear(*args)
    clear
    send_keys(args)
  end
end
```

どのようにすれば`send_keys(args, clear: true)`の形で上記の処理が実現できますか？

#### stack level too deep に関しての追記

問題が再現できなくなってしまっていたのですが、再現方法がわかりましたので追記しておきます。

`send_keys`をオーバーライドしたメソッドを定義したファイルを`selenium_webdriver_ext.rb`という名前で保存して`pry`上で動かしていたのですが、他の部分を読み込み直すために`load 'selenium_webdriver_ext.rb'`を複数回読んでしまっていたためにオーバーライドしたメソッドを更にオーバーライドしようとし続けてエラーになっていたようです。

具体的を上げておきます。

```
[1] pry(main)> require 'selenium-webdriver'
=> true
[2] pry(main)> driver = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox
=> #<Selenium::WebDriver::Driver:0x..f9315747cd0887642 browser=:firefox>
[3] pry(main)> driver.navigate.to("http://google.co.jp")
=> ""
[6] pry(main)> load 'selenium_webdriver_ext.rb'
=> true
[7] pry(main)> driver.find_element(:id, "lst-ib").send_keys("foo")
=> ""
[8] pry(main)> load 'selenium_webdriver_ext.rb'
=> true
[9] pry(main)> driver.find_element(:id, "lst-ib").send_keys("foo")
SystemStackError: stack level too deep
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

同じ環境を作成してエラーを再現しようとしましたができませんでした。

こちらにコードを置いています。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/sample-app-for-send_keys-alias/

エイリアスメソッドはここで定義しています。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/sample-app-for-send_keys-alias/blob/so-sandbox/spec/support/selenium_support.rb

`send_keys`メソッドを呼び出しているのはこちらです。

https://github.com/JunichiIto/sample-app-for-send_keys-alias/blob/so-sandbox/spec/features/users_spec.rb#L19

RSpecでこのコードを実行すると、問題なくパスします。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Rubyのバージョンは2.2.0、selenium-webdriverのバージョンは2.45.0.dev3です。
（dev3を使っているのは[このエラー](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28159499/seleniumwebdrivererrorjavascripterror-arguments0-is-undefined)をなくすためです）

ご自身の環境に僕のコードをダウンロードしてみて問題が再現するか確認してみてください。

Comment: 環境構築までして頂いてありがとうございます。環境は`2.1.3`を使用しているのですが、上げていただいたいコードでエラーが出なかったため再度自分のコードのエラーを検証しようとしたところ再現できなくなってしまっていました。大変申し訳ありません。恐らく試行錯誤してはじめのコードを書いたために既に消したつもりの別のメソッドを参照して閉まっていたのだと思います…。

Comment: `stack level too deep`エラーの原因がわかり再現出来ましたので質問に追記しておきます。この問題を回避する方法はわからないので、また別に質問を立てさせていただきます。

Answer (score 2):

Ruby 2.0以上を使っているのであれば[Module#prepend](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Module/i/prepend.html)を使うとalias method chainのようなことをしなくても同じようなことが出来て便利です。

参考: [» Ruby2.0のModule#prependは如何にしてalias_method_chainを撲滅するのか！？ TECHSCORE BLOG](http://www.techscore.com/blog/2013/01/22/ruby2-0%E3%81%AEmodule-prepend%E3%81%AF%E5%A6%82%E4%BD%95%E3%81%AB%E3%81%97%E3%81%A6alias_method_chain%E3%82%92%E6%92%B2%E6%BB%85%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B%E3%81%AE%E3%81%8B%EF%BC%81%EF%BC%9F/)

```rb
module SendKeysWithOption
  def send_keys(*args, clear: false)
    __send__(:clear) if clear
    super(*args)
  end
end

Selenium::WebDriver::Element.prepend(SendKeysWithOption)
```

Answer (score 1):

実行・検証してないので、間違っていればゴメンナサイ。

## メソッド定義

ソース [element.rb - selenium](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/source/browse/rb/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/element.rb) から `send_keys` メソッドの定義部分を引き抜いていじりました。

```
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    class Element
      alias_method :send_keys_orig, :send_keys
      def send_keys(*args, clear_flag: false)
        clear if clear_flag
        bridge.sendKeysToElement @id, Keys.encode(args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

としてみてはいかがでしょうか。

## キーワード引数と既存メソッド名の重複

テキトーにクラス作ってメソッド aaa を作って、他のメソッドのキーワード引数に aaa を使って確認し、特に問題生じないですよ、と書こうとしたのですが、今回は

```
clear if clear # 前者はメソッド、後者はローカル変数/引数
```

を実現したいのだ、ということに気付きました。

### 1. `__send__` でメソッドへ送ってしまう

上のメソッド定義と組み合わせて

```
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    class Element
      alias_method :send_keys_orig, :send_keys
      def send_keys(*args, clear: false)
        __send__(:clear) if clear
        bridge.sendKeysToElement @id, Keys.encode(args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

でどうでしょう。

### 2. メソッドであることを `()` で明示する

[ruby2.2.0ではメソッドの引数のデフォルト値に同じ名前の変数を使えない - Qiita](http://qiita.com/a_ishidaaa/items/47a8459aa5fe5512871a)
の回避法で Matz が

> ```
> In other part of Ruby, foo = foo makes foo to nil.
> To get old behavior, try foo = foo().
> ```
>
> [Bug #10314: Default argument lookup fails in Ruby 2.2 for circular
>
>   shadowed variable names - Ruby trunk - Ruby Issue Tracking
>
>   System](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/10314#note-4)

と指摘してます。
つまり、 `()` を付けちゃえばメソッド、無ければローカル変数。

```
module Selenium
  module WebDriver
    class Element
      alias_method :send_keys_orig, :send_keys
      def send_keys(*args, clear: false)
        clear() if clear
        bridge.sendKeysToElement @id, Keys.encode(args)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。キーワード引数と既存メゾット名の重複に関しては`__send__(:clear)`で解決出来ました。ただ、既存メソッドの置き換えに関しては`NameError: uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Element::Keys`が出てしまうのと、仮に出来たとしても内部実装を再度書くことになるのならやめておこうと考えています。

Comment: 小手先対応かもしれませんが、 `require 'selenium-webdriver'` 直後に `require 'selenium/webdriver/common'` を入れて、強制的に依存ライブラリを読み込んではいかがでしょうか。

Comment: requireしてみましたが、`uninitialized constant Selenium::WebDriver::Element::Keys`が出てきてしまいました。

Comment: そうでしたか。 `common.rb` で `Keys` も読み込みしているのでいけるかと思ったのですが。