# 既存クラスのメソッドを書き換えたファイルを何度も読み込む時の扱い方

Tags: ruby, pry

[ruby - 既存クラスのメソッドに追加のオプションをつける方法](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/questions/6938/%e6%97%a2%e5%ad%98%e3%82%af%e3%83%a9%e3%82%b9%e3%81%ae%e3%83%a1%e3%82%bd%e3%83%83%e3%83%89%e3%81%ab%e8%bf%bd%e5%8a%a0%e3%81%ae%e3%82%aa%e3%83%97%e3%82%b7%e3%83%a7%e3%83%b3%e3%82%92%e3%81%a4%e3%81%91%e3%82%8b%e6%96%b9%e6%b3%95) にて既存クラスのメソッドの書き換えについてお聞きしたのですが、問題が書き換えの方法ではなくファイルの読み込み方にあったために別の質問として立てさせていただきました。

以下のように`selenium-webdriver`の拡張をしたのですが、pry上で作業している時に`Selenium::Webdriver::Element`に他のメソッドを追加した時など何度も`load 'selenium_webdriver_ext.rb'` で呼び出すと2回目以降から `stack level too deep`のエラーが発生してしまいます。

#### selenium_webdriver_ext.rb

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Element
  alias_method :send_keys_orig, :send_keys  
  def send_keys(*args, clear: false)
    __send__(:clear) if clear
    send_keys_orig(*args)
  end
end
```

メソッドの書き換えを行ったファイルを`pry`から何度も読みだす時に何か良い方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Module#prepend](http://docs.ruby-lang.org/ja/2.2.0/method/Module/i/prepend.html)を使いましょう。

```rb
module SendKeysWithOption
  def send_keys(*args, clear: false)
    __send__(:clear) if clear
    super(*args)
  end
end

# 何度Module#prependが呼ばれても元のメソッドは消えないので問題なく動く
Selenium::WebDriver::Element.prepend(SendKeysWithOption)
```

Answer (score 2):

ガード条件を付けてみました。  
`send_keys_orig` がすでに存在していればエイリアスメソッドは作らないようにしています。

```
class Selenium::WebDriver::Element
  unless instance_methods.include?(:send_keys_orig)
    alias_method :send_keys_orig, :send_keys
  end 

  def send_keys(*args, clear: false)
    __send__(:clear) if clear
    send_keys_orig(*args)
  end
end
```

参考文献: [Effective Ruby](http://www.amazon.co.jp/exec/obidos/ASIN/4798139823/junic05-22/ref=nosim/) 第5章

Answer (score 1):

2回目以降の `alias_method :send_keys_orig, :send_keys` がまずいですね。オリジナルが消えてますし、メソッド自身を呼び出すことになってしまいます。

[aliasによるメソッドの再定義は危険なのでUnboundMethodかextendを使おう - るびきち](http://d.hatena.ne.jp/rubikitch/20080504/1209835550)
と、るびきちさんの著作[Ruby逆引きハンドブック](http://www.c-r.com/book/detail/705)「メソッドを再定義する」 (p.630) を用いて書き直してみました。

```
def once
  unless instance_variable_defined? :@__once_executed__
    yield
    @__once_executed__ = true
  end
end

class Selenium::WebDriver::Element
  once do
    alias_method :send_keys_orig, :send_keys  
  end
  def send_keys(*args, clear: false)
    __send__(:clear) if clear
    send_keys_orig(*args)
  end
end
```

簡単に言えば、再読込したときに `once` メソッドの引数（ブロック）は読まないので `SystemStackError: stack level too deep` が出ない、ということです。

他にも、先ほどの引用のタイトル通り、 `Module#instance_method` で `UnboundMethod` を得てから再定義というやり方、及び `Object#extend` を使ってインスタンスに再定義メソッドを突っ込むやり方があります。それらに関しては引用先を見てください。